# permutations and combinations of Arraylists in Java?

Tags: java

I have three Arraylists like this

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();    
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();    
List<String> finallist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

list1 contains items  "a","b"
list2 contains items   1 , 2, 3
how to make a finallist that will contain
"a1" "a2" "a3" "b1" "b2" "b3"

Comment: From where Letter 'C' appeared?

Comment: also, "final" is a reserved word in Java. You can't have it as a variable name.

Comment: you've said `a1, a2, a3`, but not `1a, 1b, 1c`, do you only want combinations and not permutations?

Comment: Also, where did the "c" come from to make "c1", etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the lists look like this:

```
    List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
```

then:

```
    List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String letter: list1) {
        for (String number: list2) {
            finalList.add(letter + number);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(finalList);
```