# Find all permutations(cartesian product) from a list<list<int>> in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, int

If I have n lists:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>
List<int> list2 = new List<int>
...
List<int> listn = new List<int>
```

each of them contains different number of elements,e.g.

```
list1.add(1)
list1.add(2)
list2.add(3)
list2.add(4)
list2.add(5)
list3.add(6)
...
listn.add(100000)
listn.add(100001)
```

and one list of lists

```
List<List<int>> biglist = new ArrayList<List<int>>
biglist.add(list1)
biglist.add(list2)
...
biglist.add(listn)
```

then how can I generate permuationList from the biglist that contains elements, suppose the listn has m elements:

```
[biglist.get(1).get(1),biglist.get(2).get(1), ..., biglist.get(n-1).get(1), biglist.get(n).get(1)]
[biglist.get(1).get(1),biglist.get(2).get(1), ..., biglist.get(n-1).get(1), biglist.get(n).get(2)]
...
[biglist.get(1).get(1),biglist.get(2).get(1), ..., biglist.get(n-1).get(1), biglist.get(n).get(m)]
[biglist.get(1).get(1),biglist.get(2).get(1), ..., biglist.get(n-1).get(2), biglist.get(n).get(1)]
....
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [permutations and combinations of Arraylists in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485497/permutations-and-combinations-of-arraylists-in-java)

Comment: `List<int>`, really?

Comment: please refer to the question again, thanks!

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/combinatoricslib/#3._Simple_combinations maybe

Comment: @RC. it seems that there is only one list, and my case is n list, every list has different number of elements, say 3 list, with 3,4,5 number of elements, then the final result I want is 3*4*5=60 lists, every list with 3 elements. Thanks!

Comment: @user, check my updated answer, I think that is what you want.

Comment: @Ted Hopp, thanks for your answer, but personally, the Jaskey's one is clear for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion to achieve this, to merge the first list with the tail list(a list of list).

```
public class Permutation   {
    public static List<List<Integer>> calculate(List<List<Integer>> input) {
        List<List<Integer>> result= new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();//

        if (input.isEmpty()) {  // If input is an empty list
            result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());// then add empty list to the resultand return
            return result;
        } else {//here we have a non-empty list to process
            List<Integer> head = input.get(0);//get the first list as a head
            List<List<Integer>> tail= calculate(input.subList(1, input.size()));//recursion to calculate a tail list to calculate a tail list
            for (Integer h : head) {//we merge every head element with every tail list
                for (List<Integer> t : tail) {
                    List<Integer> resultElement= new ArrayList<Integer>();//here is a new element of our result list
                    resultElement.add(h);//firstly, add the head element to this tmp list
                    resultElement.addAll(t);//add all the element from the tail list
                    result.add(resultElement);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> bigList=Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1,2),Arrays.asList(3,4),Arrays.asList(5,6));
        System.out.println(calculate(bigList));
    }
}
```

output:

```
   [[1, 3, 5, 7], [1, 3, 5, 8], [1, 3, 6, 7], [1, 3, 6, 8], [1, 4, 5, 7], [1, 4, 5, 8], [1, 4, 6, 7], [1, 4, 6, 8], [2, 3, 5, 7], [2, 3, 5, 8], [2, 3, 6, 7], [2, 3, 6, 8], [2, 4, 5, 7], [2, 4, 5, 8], [2, 4, 6, 7], [2, 4, 6, 8]]
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I have n lists (list1, list2, ..., listn, rather than 2), each of them contains different number of elements

Comment: @user, if you have three list, [1,2][3,4],[5,6]. You need [1,3][1,4][1,5][1,6],[2,3][2,4],[2,5],[2,6],[3,5][3,6][4,5][4,6]?

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to solve above problems. This is one of them. Please have a look.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(2);
    list2.add(3);
    list2.add(4);
    List<List<Integer>> biglist = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    biglist.add(list1);
    biglist.add(list2);
    print(biglist);
}

private static void print(List<List<Integer>> biglist) {
    List<Integer> list1 = biglist.get(0);
    List<Integer> list2 = biglist.get(1);
    for (Integer i : list1) {
        printCombination(i, list2);
    }
}

private static void printCombination(Integer i, List<Integer> list2) {
    for (Integer j : list2) {
        System.out.println("[" + i + ", " + j + "]");
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: it seems that it doesn't work for unknown number of list. The questions' lists are examples. What I have now are list0,list1,...listn, (the number of list can get by biglist.size() )and for each list, there are different number of elements, say, list0 has 5 elements(get by biglist.get(0).size), list1 has 6 element.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general approach to generate all combinations of elements from a list of lists:

```
public static List<List<Integer>> generateCombinations(List<List<Integer>> lists) {
    final List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    final List<Integer> accumulator = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    generateCombos(lists, result, accumulator, 0);
    return result;
}

// recursive helper method
private static void generateCombos(
        List<List<Integer>> input,
        List<List<Integer>> result,
        List<Integer> accumulator,
        int i)
{
    if (i < input.size()) {
        // add each element of the current list to the accumulator
        // and recurse with the next element of the input
        for (Integer elt : input.get(i)) {
            accumulator.add(i, elt);
            generateCombos(input, result, accumulator, i + 1);
            accumulator.remove(i);
        }
    } else {
        // add what's in the accumulator (as a new list, so we can reuse accumulator)
        result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(accumulator));
    }
}
```

Note that this generates all *combinations* of elements—one element from each list. From your example, I think that this is what you are after. If you actually want all *permutations*, you could start with this and then generate all reorderings of each element of the result (using, say, the approach presented in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305153/generating-all-possible-permutations-of-a-list-recursively)).